# assurable/assured usage

Tags: adjectives, word-usage

> If you will follow my instruction, it is more **assurable** that you
>   would achieve your goal.

assurable? or assured? What is the difference between them? I did a google search for "*more assurable*", it returns no exact match, even *assurable* seems not occurring much. So could anyone make a sentence using *assurable* so I can better understand its usage?

Comment: I doubt this is used much. I've never heard "assurable" used. The way I imagine most people would say this is "...it is more *certain* that you would achieve your goal"

Comment: Agree with @developerwjk. I would probably rewrite this sentence as follows: *If you follow my instructions, you will more likely achieve your goal.*

Answer (score 1):

[Assurable](https://www.google.com/#q=%22assurable%22) is a really uncommon word. There's no satisfactory dictionary definition that I could find (it's always listed as a derivative of "assure"), but its most common usage is related to ["life assurance"](http://www.taxplanet.com/magazine/other-topics/107-miscellaneous/467-difference-between-life-insurance-and-life-assurance).

Obviously, its context in that case will mirror that of "insurable".

The phrase["will be more assured that"](https://www.google.com/search?q="will+be+more+assured+that") is more common. But I find it just as awkward.

I would avoid the word altogether. Actually, the entire sentence is suboptimal; it seems more natural to say:

> If you follow my instructions, you're more likely to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

To give one an assurance is to win a trust.for another to follow your lead. However if your instructions do not lead to what is sought, or if the goal is mistaken for what is sought, then maybe consoling and not consulting is due. Perhaps a reassurance is what can be given since what cannot ensure (to attain) nor assure ( in an attainment), can rest in the regular method of business in an experience of its success proven of its persistance. This is where insurance salesmen would come in and, for a fee, would give that wry smile and say "i guarantee it!" Tell 'em to take a hike...around  a maintain in no hurry.